# More wildcard tag bugs - adding a related tag causes 400 error

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, wildcards

I'm aware of the couple "searching for a wildcard tag gives you a blank page" bug reports here, but wanted to report that if you search for a wildcard tag, it now works, BUT if you try to add a second tag to that search, it fails miserably with a proper (non-blank) 400 error. This is particularly bad, given that you explicitly link to the pages that give the 400 error after a search for a wildcard tag.

To reproduce, merely click any of the "related tags" links below:

[hxxp://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python~](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python~)

(and for some reason, the system won't auto-link that, and it thinks that my htmlifying of it means I'm posting two hyperlinks)

Comment: Just ran into the same problem with... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java~

Kind of surprised by Jeff Atwood's answer to this one.  It's clearly broken, the application served the broken link.  That seems strange to be "by design".

Comment: Yeah I agree. It's an incorrect design, however intentional it may or may not be. "It's a feature, not a bug!"

Answer (score -5):

Url too long; this is by design. Delete some tags or be more narrow in your wildcards.

Did you seriously expect to put 50+ tags in the URL and have it work?

Comment: No, but you shouldn't have created links that were to long (did you seriously expect to put 50+ tags in the URL and have it work?)

Comment: Uh, yeah... this answer would make more sense if *the system* wasn't generating the broken URLs.

Comment: users are generating broken wildcard searches. Python~ is too broad.

Comment: The system should then return a polite "be more specific" response. A broken link in the UI is NEVER ok if it was reached by using the UI as intended.

Comment: The system returns 400 errors by design? That seems... technically incorrect at best...